# MATLAB Mapping Toolbox Default Map Projection

Tags: matlab, map-projections

I am creating a map using `worldmap` with set lat and lon limits. What projection is MATLAB using to create the figure? Mathworks just says that it automatically chooses a 'reasonable' projection.

This is the code I'm using:

```
        figure('visible','off');

        %%% Set the map boundaries
        hi_lat=55;
        lo_lat=24.5;
        hi_lon=-54.0 ;
        lo_lon=-128.0;

        %%% Plot
        worldmap ([lo_lat hi_lat], [lo_lon hi_lon]) % lat and lon bounds of your plot
        geoshow('landareas.shp','FaceColor', 'none', 'EdgeColor', [0 0 0])
        framem off; gridm off; mlabel off; plabel off
        hold on
        states = shaperead('usastatelo', 'UseGeoCoords', true,...
            'Selector',...
            {@(name) ~any(strcmp(name,{'Alaska','Hawaii'})), 'Name'});
        geoshow(states,'FaceColor', 'none', 'EdgeColor', [0 0 0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `worldmap` equal to a variable and then try `getm`

```
h = worldmap ([lo_lat hi_lat], [lo_lon hi_lon]) % lat and lon bounds of your plot
geoshow('landareas.shp','FaceColor', 'none', 'EdgeColor', [0 0 0])
framem off; gridm off; mlabel off; plabel off
hold on
states = shaperead('usastatelo', 'UseGeoCoords', true,...
        'Selector',...
        {@(name) ~any(strcmp(name,{'Alaska','Hawaii'})), 'Name'});
    geoshow(states,'FaceColor', 'none', 'EdgeColor', [0 0 0])

getm(h,'MapProjection')
```